# Core Telephony framework partially public in 4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Since I don't want to jailbreak my iPhone i'm developing a personal application that needs to access the Core Telephony framework.

In 4.x Core Telephony framework has gone partially public but most of its futures are still hidden and kept private.

I've joust downloaded the header files form seriot.ch

I've found a list of all the known [CoreTelephony functions](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/CoreTelephonyFunctions) 
but i'm not able to make my code do what should be supposed to do. Some suggestion ?

In these useless case refuse all incoming calls.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {        
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];    
callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* call){
   if (call.callState == CTCallStateIncoming) {         
      CTCallDisconnect(call);
   }
};  
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the public CoreTelephony call events handler with the private CoreTelephony functions like CTCallDisconnect. You can see a working example of the required private event handler code here: http://tech.ruimaninfo.com/?p=83 - they key bits:

```
// Register our event handler
id ct = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(ct, NULL, callback, NULL, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);

// Our callback
static void callback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    NSString *notifyname=(NSString *)name;
    if ([notifyname isEqualToString:@"kCTCallIdentificationChangeNotification"])
    {
        NSDictionary *info = (NSDictionary *)userInfo;
        CTCall *call = (CTCall *)[info objectForKey:@"kCTCall"];
        NSString *caller = CTCallCopyAddress(NULL, call);
        NSLog(@"Incoming call: %@",caller);
        CTCallDisconnect(call);
    }
 }
```

I've confirmed this working on iOS5.1

Comment: This is not being called when call is connected or disconnected