# I Need to make the call from the myapplication itself how is it possible?

Tags: iphone, ios4, addressbook, telephony

I Want In my application to make call and When  the call get ended than simply return to the application itself is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official apple link may be use full to You

[Coretelephoney demo example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreTelephonyDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010746)

good Luck

Answer (score 1):

You could use below

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:#######"]];
```

Edited: Handling call termination notification.

[Core Telephony framework partially public in 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644557/core-telephony-framework-partially-public-in-4-0-but)

[iPhone SDK: Launching an app after call ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312666/iphone-sdk-launching-an-app-after-call-ends)

Comment: i Want to redial  the call  to the same number after the call get ended i want this procedure to  continue until i press the Stop Button in the app Thank you for answering

Comment: don't beg for rep. If the answer is right, it should be accepted. If not, or the OP just doesn't accept answers properly, begging won't help.

Comment: @Ken White :Dude,Mind your language,you should not talk this way on the forum, Don't make it dirty by such harsh comment, if you don't like the answer stackOverFlow has given the right to downvote, use that, just Would advice you not to write such word again for anyone.AND Do'nt forget everyone, who is the part of the forum investing there time to help others. and have right to ask for acceptance.