# when can i was find iPhone app sample code for used CoreTelephony framework?

Tags: iphone, core-telephony

I have requirement block the incoming call, outgoing call and sms. so any one share your knowledge how to do that task.

Then give some samples or sample code using CoreTelephony framework in iPhone SDK.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this for CoreTelephony

- http://tech.ruimaninfo.com/?p=83
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=CoreTelephony

see this  [Core Telephony framework partially public in 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644557/core-telephony-framework-partially-public-in-4-0)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. you posted CoreTelephony url is Titanium Framework application, not for iOS native application. Then second url  how can i use can you share some knowledge about that.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are not possible on iOS. You can not block calls/SMS/MMS in any way.

[`CoreTelephony`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) will only allow your app to detect incomming calls if it is running in the foreground. You will not be able to detect the number of the person calling. This ment to be used in for example a VOIP client so that it can pause the VOIP conversation when a phone call some in.

You cannot interacte SMS/MMS at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe blocking a call/sms is not possible in IOS .
But you can handle it using application delegate method -

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Refer: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for your feed back, can you give some sample using CoreTelephony framework.

Answer (score 0):

pls read Apple docs before asking features. Apple clearly states You cannot  alter calls, in or out, in any way.